# GUI Interface exception in eclipse

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

I am a new comer to java and currently teaching myself via the *HeadFirst java book*.
I was going through GUI interfaces and the code from the book does not seem to run,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class SimpleGui1 implements ActionListener {


     JButton Button;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleGui1 gui = new SimpleGui1();
        gui.go();
    }

    public void go(){ 

         JFrame frame = new JFrame();
         JButton button = new JButton("click me");
         button.addActionListener(this);

         frame.getContentPane().add(button);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.setSize(300,300);
         frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {

        Button.setText("I have been clicked");
    }

}

The exception : 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What was the exception?

Comment: I guess NullPointerException here: **Button.setText("I have been clicked");**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class member variable `Button` is never initialized. Rather another with a different name (Java is case sensitive) is defined locally in the `go` method.

In the `ActionListener` you can simply use the `ActionEvent` source to determine the  source of the `Action`:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

   JButton button = (JButton) event.getSource();
   button.setText("I have been clicked");
}
```

This removes the need to have the `JButton` as a class member variable.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize **button**, it's still null.

You're having a NullPointerException.